# SVG icons for Point style are not loaded in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, svg, icon, angular

I have a case in which I should display icons for locations on the map. But, it seems like OpenLayers has issues accessing page's Assets folder. Or there's another issue I'm not aware of, because I can't see the icons on the map.

I'm using this code to set the Icon in the style function:

```typescript
export interface FacilityIcons {
  [key: number]: string
}
/* After initializing in a different service it looks like this:
{
  1001: 'iconOne.svg',
  1002: 'iconTwo.svg',
  // ...
}
*/

export const getFacilityLocationStyle =
  (facilityIcons: FacilityIcons): StyleFunction =>
  (feature: FeatureLike, resolution: number): Style | Style[] => {
    const { subtype } = feature.getProperties();
    const icon = facilityIcons[subtype];
    // return icon when it matches subtype
    // subtype === 1001 => iconOne.svg

    return new Style({
      image: new Icon({
        src: `./assets/icons/facilities/${icon}`,
        crossOrigin: '*'
        // I tried also with size, scale, color but without effect
        // Weirdly enough, when I try this URL, it works
        // src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/data/icon.png',
      })
    });
  };
```

The UI uses the assets folder on other places (toolbar) and Icons are displayed correctly. So I believe the path is correct. Console shows no error, and when checking the Network tab in Dev Tools, I can see two calls to obtain the icon with the correct name and type. And the Icon is shown when I check the Response of 304 call.
[image: Load svg icon]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I really thought this will be a simple thing.

**EDIT:**
SVG code

```xml
<svg id="Park_1" data-name="Park 1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <defs>
    <style>.cls-1{fill:#08f;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}</style>
  </defs>
  <title>PARKING</title>
  <rect class="cls-1" width="600" height="600" rx="63.03" ry="63.03"/>
  <path class="cls-2" d="M128.36,79.09,325.43,79q67.07,0,106.62,38.86t39.59,92q0,55.05-39,94.28T326.19,343.45l-87.62,0L238.65,521l-110.08,0ZM238.48,160l.05,102.49,51.24,0q68.64,0,68.62-51.28,0-28.78-18.36-40T277.39,160Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: 304 suggests the image is cached so it could be a problem with the SVG, e.g. to be drawn to canvas it must width and height attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it

Comment: Thanks for the hint, seems like it's Firefox issue. It works nicely in Safari

Comment: Firefox will treat the image as zero size, but even if it does appear to work the results can be inconsistent (e.g. it may depend on the size of the canvas element being drawn to).

Comment: Can you provide your icon svg?

Comment: @TomazicM added to question

Comment: Could not replicate your problem in plain JS.

Comment: @TomazicM That SVG will not work in Firefox, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61784186/10118270

Comment: @Mike You are right, I forgot to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing it looks like the only way to display icon in all browsers and have it's size under control is to set `width` and `height` attributes in SVG itself. These values can be changed when defining `Icon` in OL with either options `width` and `height` or with the `scale` option.

So if the SVG is defined as

```html
<svg id="Park_1" data-name="Park 1" width="24" height="24"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <defs>
    <style>.cls-1{fill:#08f;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}</style>
  </defs>
  <title>PARKING</title>
  <rect class="cls-1" width="600" height="600" rx="63.03" ry="63.03"/>
  <path class="cls-2" d="M128.36,79.09,325.43,79q67.07,0,106.62,38.86t39.59,92q0,55.05-39,94.28T326.19,343.45l-87.62,0L238.65,521l-110.08,0ZM238.48,160l.05,102.49,51.24,0q68.64,0,68.62-51.28,0-28.78-18.36-40T277.39,160Z"/>
</svg>
```

then icon with the size 32x32 can be defined as:

```
new Icon({
  src: `./assets/icons/facilities/${icon}`,
  crossOrigin: '*',
  width: 32,
  height: 32
})
```

This is image from Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That was a tricky one.